# iOS - reference active storyboard view controller from external class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm really new to Objective C and I've got an application with a storyboard with a ViewController with the `MyViewController` class. I then have CDVPlugin (for my cordova application). From one of the methods in my cordova application I want to be able to reference the Active ViewController and call one of the functions from it. I have imported the `MyViewController.h` header and I was thinking maybe there is a way to make one a delegate for the other but I feel like this is the wrong way to approach this?

Any ideas?

Comment: In MyViewController.h, you can declare the function, do its implementation in .m file and in your Active view controller intialize "MyViewCOntroller" class, use its object to access the function.

Comment: Do you mean, for example `MyViewController * myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init]` and then `[myViewController function]` is this applicable if I want to use it to segue to another ViewController? I'm not comfortable with objective C yet and this feels to me like it would be instantiating an unnecessary view controller... or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: I also need to reference the specific one because I want to use performSegueWithIdentifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current root view controller for the application using:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController
```

The root view controller might be the active view controller, or it might be a navigation controller, in which case you might want something like:

```
UIViewController *active = ((UINavigationController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController).visibleViewController
if [active isKindOfClass: [MyViewController class]] {
    MyViewController *myViewController = (MyViewController *)active
    // Call any methods you need to on myViewController
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, is there a way that I can confirm that it is a viewcontroller of a specific type i.e. `MyViewController`?

Comment: @AlecGamble  Sure, I updated the answer with an example of doing that